Gazebo sim not starting because of undefined symbol from libQt5Quick.so.5
I am trying to launch a python script from within matlab.
system('python3 /home/niuniek/meldog-ros/src/power_unit_v3/launch/power_unit_run_simulation_node.py')

This script launches gazebo and a ros2 node for sending trajectories into a simulation.
def launch_gazebo_simulation():
    # Open a new terminal and launch Gazebo simulation
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'bash', '-c', 'cd meldog-ros && timeout 13s ros2 launch power_unit_v3 power_unit_v3_optimization.launch.py'])
    time.sleep(13)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'bash', '-c', 'killall ruby'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # launch_gazebo_simulation()
    launch_gazebo_simulation()

This python script executes just fine from a regular terminal, but when i try to launch the matlab program, gazebo does not launch and i get this error message:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2] Library error for [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libignition-gazebo6-ign.so.6.16.0]: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN18QTextureGlyphCache8populateEP11QFontEngineiPKjPK11QFixedPoint, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API
[ERROR] [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-2]: process has died [pid 16310, exit code 255, cmd 'ruby $(which ign) gazebo -r -v -v4 empty.sdf --force-version 6'].

I've tried launching Matlab from root and it didnt work, i also tried using a different terminal (xterm, terminator) to no effect.
